# Why does the While Loop keeps executing infinitely in C++ even when the condition is met?

Tags: c++

I made **Rolling Dice** Program in **C++**,
it's working well except for that the **While Loop** doesn't break *(attempt != 6)*.
It keeps filling random numbers (1-6) infinitely, it's supposed to stop when *attempt == 6* but it doesn't.
Can you adjust my code and tell me what's wrong with? I'm a **beginner** in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int attempt = 1+(rand()%6);   //random number generating for the Attempts
    int numOfAt = 0;              //setting value to Number of Attempts

    while (attempt != 6 ){
        int attempt = 1+(rand()%6);
        cout << "You rolled a " << attempt << endl;     //keeps executing this line infinitely
        numOfAt++;
    }
    cout << "It took you " << numOfAt << " attempts to roll a six."; 
}
```

Comment: `int attempt = 1+(rand()%6);` inside a loop -> `attempt = 1+(rand()%6);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `attempt`s. The `attempt` inside the loop body is not visible from the outside of the loop body. `while (attempt != 6 )` is outside the loop body (before the loop body), so it sees the first `attempt`, which is not changed in the loop.

To fix, remove the declaration of `attempt` inside the loop body and overwrite the `attempt` before the loop instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int attempt = 1+(rand()%6);   //random number generating for the Attempts
    int numOfAt = 0;              //setting value to Number of Attempts

    while (attempt != 6 ){
        attempt = 1+(rand()%6); // remove "int"
        cout << "You rolled a " << attempt << endl;     //keeps executing this line infinitely
        numOfAt++;
    }
    cout << "It took you " << numOfAt << " attempts to roll a six."; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables, both called `attempt`. You are testing one and changing the other. Remove the `int` from the `int attempt = 1+(rand()%6);` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note you are redefining `int attempt` in the `while` loop, I suspect that may be you issue.
I suggest you change it from `int attempt` to `attempt`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't redefine attempt in while loop, due to scope of variable there is a mismatch of comparison of "attempt" variable (the one outside while and the one inside while).

Updated loop:

```
while(attempt != 6) {
    attempt = 1+(rand()%6); //updated line
    .
    .
}
```